# How to stop gearman worker

Tags: php, multithreading, multiprocessing, gearman

I have created simple script client.php and worker.php with the help of gearmand documentation which reverse the string. String is given in script client.php. I have execute worker.php first then client.php. As desired , client.php reverse the given string. Now i want to update the function of worker but updating function does not change the behavior of worker function.
So I want to stop worker via php code.

Please give suggestion to solve my problem

Comment: How are you running the worker.php?  Is it running in the background or in the foreground?  Are you on a *nix system or Windows?

Comment: I am using unix system. I am running php script in cmd.

Comment: If you run your worker using cmd, the only way I think that you have to kill the worker process.  After you update your code, just start your worker again.